# Open Source alternative to "Campton" font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

I'm searching for an open source alternative to Campton (Light and Bold) from http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rene-bieder/campton/.

Does anybody know if there is for example a google font that looks like Campton? Searching and comparing over 700 fonts would be pretty bad.

Or is there even a service which can identify similar open source fonts to commercial fonts?

Comment: Take a picture of Campton, upload it to https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ and it should identify the font, and/or some similar ones

Comment: A service like that would be nice! But I love browsing for fonts. :) You can try searching in Google Fonts with some filtering. Have only the Sans Serif box checked, and try messing with the thickness slider. There are some good ones in there.

Comment: I suspect you mean free and not open source?

Comment: Yes, free or open source. The license should allow unlimited commercial use for web, print, apps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a geometric sans font. So looking in [those categories on FontSquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5Bclassifications%5D%5B0%5D=sans%20serif&filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=sans%2C%20geometric) gives you several options.
But the one I think comes closer is [Poppins](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Poppins), avalable in Google Fonts:

[image: Poppins Font]